# How to connect between prototype chain of objects and HTML representing them?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, prototype

I have a card game, and cards are represented by Javascript objects that are created as instances of class (`card > card-type > card-instance`). I did it like this so that the cards can share methods.

Then I construct the HTML, and the cards suppose to be able to do all kinds of stuff, like move or attack for example.

move is defined in `Card.prototype.move = function...` and attack is `UnitCard.prototype.attack`

and now I am trying to connect the Card objects to their corresponding HTML elements, so that I will be able to so something like

```
$('#board').on('click', '.card', function (e) {
  this.move(this.location, newLocation);
});
```

An idea I had is to make all the data and functions of the cards part of the DOM, and insert an object somewhere along the prototype chain of the DOM elements, so that the HTML of that card will have a move function. I know this idea is a bit crazy, but I am trying to avoid constant lookups inside objects (find the clicked card by name in the array of all cards and then if other cards that have influence on the action find them in the dom and then find them in the object etc...)

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE - Current Code:**

```
var Card = function (type, name, epoch) {
  var cardHtml =  document.createElement('div');

  cardHtml.className += "card";
  cardHtml.id = name;
  cardHtml.cardType = type;
  cardHtml.cardName = name;
  cardHtml.cardEpoch = epoch;

  this.cardHtml = cardHtml;
}

var Agent = function (cardProps, subtype, description, strike, shield, price) {
  //fixed
  Card.apply(this, cardProps);
  this.subtype = subtype;
  this.price = price; //agenda

 //changable
  this.cardHtml.innerHTML = ss.tmpl['cards-agent'].render({
    name: this.name,
  });
  this.cardHtml.strike = strike;
  this.cardHtml.shield = shield;
  this.cardHtml.location = []; //board/hand/deck/grveyard
}


Agent.prototype = Object.create(Card.prototype);

Agent.prototype.move = function (currentLocation, newLocarion) {
    console.log('move');
}
```

Comment: Make a parameter in `Card` take the _HTMLElement_ and wrap it, then work with `new Card(myNodeThatIsACard)`.

Comment: @PaulS. I added the code, I think I did what you meant

Comment: [Bad idea.](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) Not only because it doesn't work well, you're mixing representation and behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi I know the reservations for extending dom, I think the benefits here might outweigh the potential problems.

Comment: `cardHtml.id = name;` looks really suspicious in that you might create non-unique _IDs_

Comment: @PaulS. The IDs are unique. I make sure of that since I create the names of the cards

Comment: @IlyaD why not create a dictionary object like `var dict = {}; dict[idkeyhere] = {node: foo, card: bar};`? Just make sure you clean up from it too when you remove nodes/cards. Now, when you want the _Node_ you do `dict[id].node`, or if you want the card `dict[id].card`, so e.g. in your listener, `dict[this.id].card.move(x, y)`

Comment: @PaulS. What if for the sake of this issue we assume the HTML is not part of the view but part of the functionality (which I am starting to think is more accurate), and if so, we are making an unnecessary duplicity here by creating two object that represent the same entity. So why not put all of it into the DOM HTML object?

Comment: @IlyaD because you want a map from the _DOM_ to a _Card_ instance; having `a = {}; b = {}; a.b = b;` is great, but then doing `b.a = a;` creates a circular reference; which as we all know, is evil. The problem doesn't arise from the fact you want to interact with your `card`, it arises from wanting link from _Node_ to your custom _Object_ as opposed to the other way around. Remember, the only "good way" to store custom things on a _Node_ is with _data-*_ attributes. It's not too hard to set up the dictionary in a closure along with your constructor.

Comment: Why not store the instance of the card on the card's html element's data?

Comment: Have you considered looking into MVC frameworks like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org), [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org), or [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com)? A lot of the functionality you're looking for is available out-of-the-box with these frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to the instance on the element's data object.

```
var Card = function (type, name, epoch) {
  var cardHtml =  document.createElement('div');

  cardHtml.className += "card";
  cardHtml.id = name;
  cardHtml.cardType = type;
  cardHtml.cardName = name;
  cardHtml.cardEpoch = epoch;

  this.cardHtml = cardHtml;
  $(cardHtml).data("card",this);
}
```

Now you can access it within events as needed.

```
$('#board').on('click', '.card', function (e) {
  var card = $(this).data('card');
  card.move(card.location, newLocation);
});
```

This of course assumes you can use jquery, per the jquery you're using in your question.

Comment: Minor wording issue.  `.data` won't actually store it "on" the element.  Behind the scenes jquery stores it in some sort of hash or something.

Comment: This solution is really cool, though one question: isn't data meant for primitives only? is it a jQuery manipulation to enable it to store object on data attribute? And if so, will it not make performance impact?

Comment: It can store anything. Since you're just storing a reference, it shouldn't impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two additional options.

You could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a click handler in which `this` is actually your object instead of the dom element.

```
el.onclick = (function(){/* ... */}).bind(yourObj);
```

In this case, within your function, `this` would be your object instead of the dom element.  As long as your object stores a reference to the dom element itelf, then you're set.

---

Another option would be to define the click handler within a closure which has a variable containing the object.

```
function bindHanlder(yourObj, el){
    el.onclick = function(){
        // "yourObj" can be used here.
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your board has specific places where your cards can be placed.

You should have a Board object containing an array of Places, something like:

```
function Card(divId){

   this.divId = divId;

   //generate Card html elements with jquery
}

function Place(divId){

   var currentCard = null;

   //attach this javascript object to an html element
   this.divId = divId;

   //register events of this Place where this Place has this.divId
   /*
   $(document).on("click", this.divId, function(){

   });
   */

   this.setCard = function(card){
      currentCard = card;

      //use jquery to add Card html elements to this Place html element
   }

}

function Board(){

   var places= new Array();

   this.addPlace = function(place){
      places.push(place);
   }

   this.moveCard = function(card, toPlace){

      toPlace.setCard(card);
   }
}

var card1 = new Card("#divCard1");
var card2 = new Card("#divCard2");

var place1 = new Place("#divPlace1");
var place2 = new Place("#divPlace2");

var board = new Board();

board.addPlace(place1);
board.addPlace(place2);

board.moveCards(card1,place1);
```

This is really off the top of my head. I don't even know if it runs or not. It's just to give you an idea. Interpret it as pseudo code.

Good luck!